# captured, tagged, and then released

Tags: probability

A forest contains 20 elk, of which 5 are captured,
tagged, and then released. A certain time later, 4
of the 20 elk are captured. What is the probability
that 2 of these 4 have been tagged? What assumptions
are you making?

I don't understand where to start...Just started with probability very confusing..Can someone help me understand this problem please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twenty elks are in the population.  Among these five elks are tagged; and hence fifteen elks are untagged.

We assume tagging does not make an elk easier or harder to catch again, and that the population is well mixed.   That is that each of every elk is equally likely to be among those caught.

We want the probability of selecting *two* from the *five* tagged elks and *two* from the *fifteen* untagged elks, out of all ways to select any *four* from the *twenty* elks.

**PS:** That will be the probability that *exactly* two of the four are tagged.   Maybe you wanted the probability that *at least* two of the four are tagged.   Can you adjust the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What is the probability that a random elk you pick is tagged? How many different ways are there for there to be $2$ tagged elk out of the $4$ you pick?

Comment: probability that a random elk you pick is tagged =5/20 ... choosing 2 out  4 4c2  ...so is it 5/20*4c2

Comment: @G.Lane Not quite. What is the probability of catching two tagged and then two not tagged elks in that order?  Multiply that by the ways to arrange the elk-kinds to get the answer.